# jQuery find all elements with certain attribute and get the value of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get values of every existing 'ajaxify' attribute on the page.

```
$('[ajaxify]')
```

This gets me `361` objects. How to get the values?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each or http://api.jquery.com/map if you want to create an array of the values. I'd also suggest you use a `data-*` attribute for this as `ajaxify` is non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all value as an array, use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map)**, **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)** and **[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get)** methods

```
$('[ajaxify]').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('ajaxify')
}).get()
```

**FYI :** Always try to use [`data-*`(eg :`data-ajaxify`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for custom attribute, since it's the standard way to use custom attribute. In than case you can use **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data)** method to get attribute value.

Comment: Thanks! It's a facebook page so I can't do much about it :)

Comment: @bbPi : glad to help you :)